# In a polars dataframe, filter a column of type list by another column of type list

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a [polars](/questions/tagged/polars) dataframe as below:

Example input:

```py
import polars as pl
d = pl.DataFrame()
df = d.with_columns(pl.lit([1]).alias('user_id'), 
                    pl.lit([[1,2,3,4]]).alias('items'),
                    pl.lit([[3,4,5,6]]).alias('popular_items'))

┌─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┐
│ user_id     ┆ items       ┆ popular_items │
│ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---           │
│ i64         ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1           ┆[1, 2, 3, 4] ┆ [3, 4, 5, 6]  │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

I want to filter `popular_items` column by removing any items that are in `items` column for each `user_id`

I have been trying to get it to work but have been unsuccessful due to various issues. In all likelihood, I am probably overcomplicating things.

The expected output should be as follows:

```py
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│ user_id     ┆ items       ┆ popular_items ┆ suggested │
│ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---       │
│ i64         ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]     ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1           ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4]┆ [3, 4, 5, 6]  ┆ [5, 6]    │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴───────────┘
```

It seems like the solution should be simple, but it seems to escape me after some time now trying different things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a "simple" way to do this.

You can explode the list and use `.is_in` to check if it is in the other.

```
(df.explode("popular_items")
   .with_columns(is_in = pl.col("popular_items").is_in("items").is_not()))
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ user_id ┆ items       ┆ popular_items ┆ is_in │
│ ---     ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---   │
│ i64     ┆ list[i64]   ┆ i64           ┆ bool  │
╞═════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1       ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ 3             ┆ false │
│ 1       ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ 4             ┆ false │
│ 1       ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ 5             ┆ true  │
│ 1       ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ 6             ┆ true  │
└─────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

Which you could `.filter`, turn back into a list, and `.join`.

```
df.join(
   (df.explode("popular_items")
      .filter(pl.col("popular_items").is_in("items").is_not())
      .groupby("user_id")
      .agg(suggested="popular_items")),
   on="user_id"
)
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│ user_id ┆ items       ┆ popular_items ┆ suggested │
│ ---     ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]     ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ [1, 2, … 4] ┆ [3, 4, … 6]   ┆ [5, 6]    │
└─────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴───────────┘
```

Perhaps it's better to explode both lists and use an [Anti-join](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/transformations/joins/#anti-join) to compute the "difference".

```
difference = (
   df.explode("popular_items")
     .join(
        df.explode("items"),
        left_on=["user_id", "popular_items"],
        right_on=["user_id", "items"],
        how="anti"
     )
     .groupby("user_id", maintain_order=True)
     .agg(suggested="popular_items")
)

df.join(difference, on="user_id")
```

Comment: ani-join is definitely a useful feature to know about, both solutions are great